# Batch script to enable windows account

Tags: windows

I am in a need to enable a windows local user account (Buildingblock) on a number of branch servers. Usually how i do it is start->computer Managment-> Local users -> Right click on the required user and uncheck the "The account is disabled" option. As I have to do it on a number of machines remotley, is there a way to do it by running a script? If so can you please let me know of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do this:

```
net user someone /active:yes
```

See more info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251394) or run `net help user`.